# React Native, changing Image uri dynamically - image doesn't change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm mapping through an array of objects, which each have their own image path:

```
this.props.images = [{url:'myimage.png'},{url:'myimage.png'},{url:'myimage.png'}];
```

In my render I have something like:

```
this.props.images.map((img) => { return (<Image source={uri: img.url} />)};
```

This works fine, the images appear. However, when I dynamically re-order the images array, the images don't change (while their dynamically transferred styles do change).

Its important to note, that my array is a prop managed through redux. So the component re-renders when it changes. To test this, I logged to the console using the onLayout callback, and verified it was called each time the state changed (even though the image itself did not change source).

I believe it has to do with the instance of the image itself not being removed first, but the array knows nothing about what is causing the re-order of elements.

Any ideas about how to solve this?

Comment: arent props supposed to be immutable?

Comment: the props are changing through redux state, the state objects in redux are immutable and new ones are created in the reducer, but it wouldn't make sense for props themselves to be immutable if they're being used for state.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can  add key to the Image
this.props.images.map((img) => { return ()};

Comment: May be this should be a comment instead of an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use this:-

```
 <Image source ={{uri : 'YourUrl'+ new Date() }}/>
```

Adding `new Date()` worked for me